# Call function from within angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have an Angular factory with some functions.
What i am trying to do is use myService to get the data and after its a success call another function that belongs to the factory:

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', function($http) {
    return {

        myFunction: function() {

            MyService.getData().then(
                function(response) {
                    var something = response;
                    this.anotherFunction(something); //returns undefined
                },

                function (error) {
                    //something terrible happened
                }
            );
        },


        anotherFunction: function(something) {
            console.log(something) //will not run
        }
     }
});
```

It fails because `this.anotherFunction` returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scope issue - `this` does not refer to the function in the place you are using it. Try:

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', function($http) {
    var factory ={}

    factory.anotherFunction = function(something) {
        console.log(something) //will not run
    }

    factory.myFunction = function() {

        MyService.getData().then(
            function(response) {
                var something = response;
                    factory.anotherFunction(something); 
                },
                function (error) {
                    //something terrible happened
                }
            );
    }
    return factory;
});
```

Now we initialise `factory` as an object, assign functions to it, and return it. This means you should be able to reference `factory.anotherFunction()` from inside the first function. Although I've re-ordered them, as I'm not entirely sure if hoisting will apply in this method - but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: still the same, it returns undefined if i call it without the this

Comment: yes it works now, also i found that if i set a variable of this like that,
var that = this;
and then calling the function like that.anotherFunction(); works as well! Should i post it as a second answer?

Comment: Yeah, post away - that's also another good solution and totally slipped my mind!

Answer (score 0):

Except from the solution that @millerbr provided, which works perfectly fine i found that using a var that = this; variable solves the problem as well:

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', function($http) {
return {
    var that = this;

    myFunction: function() {

        MyService.getData().then(
            function(response) {
                var something = response;
                that.anotherFunction(something); //returns undefined
            },

            function (error) {
                //something terrible happened
            }
        );
    },


    anotherFunction: function(something) {
        console.log(something) //will not run
    }
 }
```

});

Comment: from what i can understand it is like caching the this; then using its cached version altho it has been changed

Comment: Almost! But it's not a cached version. You're storing the reference to the factory itself so that later on, you can still refer to it and use functions (or variables) it has.

Answer (score -2):

You must write it like this

```
   myApp.factory('myFactory', function($http) {
    var self{};
    self.anotherFunction = function(something) {
            console.log(something) //will not run
        } ;   
    self.myFunction = function() {
                MyService.getData().then(
                    function(response) {
                        var something = response;
                        self.anotherFunction(something); //returns undefined
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        //something terrible happened
                    }
               };
return self;
});
```

Comment: So, exactly what I posted but with a different name for the variable?

Comment: o_o, could be that you type faster :)...this is service as a factory way of writing...not groundbreaking govt secrets :p chill dude.